# Why `isArray()` is written on `Array` instead of `Array prototype`?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Out of curiosity, I just want to know the reason.

All array methods like `map`, `forEach`, `reduce` are written on `Array.prototype` and so that, i can use like this

```js
let sum = [1,2,3,4,5].reduce( (acc, value) => acc+value, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Unlike all these methods, `isArray()` usage is like

```js
let isArray = Array.isArray([1,2,3]); // I can't use [1,2,3].isArray(); :(
console.log(isArray);
```

Is there any reason behind this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why `isArray()` is written on `Array` instead of `Array prototype`?

In case the answer is "no, it's not an array":

```js
let obj = {};
let isArray = obj.isArray(); // TypeError: obj.isArray is not a function
```

The purpose of `isArray` is to provide a means of checking whether something that may or may not be an array is an array. If `isArray` were on the Array prototype, it wouldn't be accessible unless the answer was "yes, it's an array."

---

To be fair, it *would* have been possible to put `isArray` on `Object.prototype` and have it return `false`, then override it in `Array.prototype` to return `true`. That still would have failed for `undefined` and `null`, though:

```js
let x = null;
let isArray = x.isArray(); //  TypeError: Cannot read property 'isArray' of null
```

...and would have unnecessarily polluted the members list of all other object types in the standard library. Making it a static that you call with the thing to be tested as an argument just made more sense — at the point where `Array.isArray` was added. (What may have made more sense still would have been for `typeof` to work fundamentally differently than it does, but that ship sailed in 1995, so...)

Comment: but all the others would raise the same error, try to .reduce object or .forEach object. Why is this one an exception, would you know?

Comment: @Dellirium: The goal is to test whether something is an array. You use the other methods on something that you already know to be an array (perhaps because you checked first with `isArray`).

Comment: Because you use `reduce` when you know it is used on array, but you use `isArray` on something you don't know whether it is array or not.

Answer (score 2):

If the object is not typeof array. In that case we would have to add the method isArray() to all data types.

For example string.isArray() would return false, object.isArray() would return false etc.

Also as  ponury-kostek pointed it out in the comments. Try doing that with null or undefined. It is not possible

It is better to have it as a function which takes an input and validates it

Comment: `In that case we would have to add the method isArray() to all data types`. Try with `null` or `undefined` :>

Answer (score 0):

Any `Object` can have `.isArray()` property:

```js
o = { isArray: () => true }
console.log(o.isArray())      // true 

a = []; a.isArray = () => false
console.log(a.isArray())      // false
```

or `.prototype.isArray()`:

```js
Object.prototype.isArray = () => true
Array.prototype.isArray = () => false
console.log({}.isArray(), [].isArray()) // true false
```

**Update** never mind ..

```js
Array.isArray = () => false
console.log(Array.isArray([]))    // false
```

but you can still add it:

```js
Object.prototype.isArray = false
Array.prototype.isArray = true

console.log([].isArray, {}.isArray, "".isArray, (0).isArray, (false).isArray) // but doesn't work for null and undefined
```